# image_tag (or html <img>) alt's (tooltips) not appearing in IE8 or FF, but do appear in IE7?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5 (Running in Development Mode on localhost)

I haven't been able to find an answer for this.   In IE8 and FF, the alts (tooltips) do not appear on mouseover.   Yet for some reason in IE7 they do.    I'd guess this is some basic knowledge I'm missing or there's something in my stylesheets that's killing the tooltips in IE7/IE8?   I'm not using a tooltip script or plugin.

The two main ways I'm using image_tags:

```
<%= image_tag("show_group.png", :size => "64x64", :alt => "Show Group") %>

<%=link_to image_tag ("menu_icon_make_new_item.png", :size => "38x27", :alt => 
"Make new item",  :id => 'item_select_menu', :class => 'nothing2'), {},
:onclick =>'dialog_back_to_new_item_select_menu(); return false' %>
```

Although I'm pretty sure it's not a Rails thing because even this hand coded img tag doesn't show it's alt on hover in IE8/FF (but does show it in IE7).

```
<span id="show_user_panel_arrow"><img src="\images\user_panel_expand.png" 
 alt="show bulk user panel" id="user_panel_arrow" /></span>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

`alt` is the wrong attribute for tooltips. Old versions of IE improperly used the alt attribute for mouseover titles.  alt is the alternative text that gets displayed if the image does not come up.

Use the `title` attribute.

example:

```
<img src="mypic.jpg" alt="Description" title="This shows up on mouseover" />
```

Comment: OMG I feel like souch a total Moron.   Thank you very much!

Comment: It's an attribute, not a tag, and the alt attribute shouldn't usually contain a description — that leads to the "Large Yellow Bullet" problem — http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html#howlers

Comment: Ah for when only text is displayed by a device so the 'browser' shows the text in place of the picture it can't display?  Thanks!

Comment: Or reads it out because the user has a vision related disability, or is read by a search indexer that isn't going to burn CPU on decoding and trying to analyse the image, or or or :)

Answer (score 8):

Use title option to display text in rails 3.

```
<%= image_tag 'show_group.png',:title => 'show_group'  %>
```

When mouse hover over the show_group.png , it will show the text "show_group".

Answer (score 3):

This "feature" was [removed in IE8](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200908/ie_8_does_not_display_alt_text_in_a_tooltip/) and other browsers never had it. The alt attribute is for text to display instead of the image and wasn't intended as additional information. That is what the title attribute is for.